# How can I show if the eigenvalues of the Hessian is greater than $\alpha$, then the function is strongly convex?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, convex-analysis, hessian-matrix

If $f$ is strongly convex then there exists an $\alpha >0$ and a convex function $g$ such that $$f(x) = g(x) + \frac{\alpha}{2} \|x\|^{2}$$

How can I show that if the eigenvalues of $H_f(x) \geq \alpha$, then $f$ is strongly convex?

Answer (score 3):

Your wording is a little ambiguous, here is the precise claim I believe you are asking about:

**Claim.**
Let $h\colon \mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R$ be a twice differentiable function on $\mathbb R^n$ whose Hessian's eigenvalues are all at least $\alpha$. Then there exists a convex function $k(x)$ such that $h(x)=k(x)+\tfrac{\alpha}{2}\|x\|^2$.

**Proof.** Observe that
$$
\frac{\partial }{\partial x^i}\frac{\partial }{\partial x^j}\bigl(h(x)-\frac{\alpha}{2}\|x\|^2\bigr)=\frac{\partial }{\partial x^i}\frac{\partial }{\partial x^j}h(x) - \alpha I_{ij},
$$
where $I$ is the $n\times n$ identity matrix. Since adding or subtracting a multiple of the identity matrix has the effect of shifting the eigenvalues (since that is the effect it has on the characteristic polynomial), it follows that the Hessian of $h(x)-\tfrac{\alpha}{2}\|x\|^2$ has all eigenvalues non-negative, meaning that the function $h(x)-\tfrac{\alpha}{2}\|x\|^2$ is convex. Finally, we set $k(x)$ to equal this function.

Comment: Isn't this proving your claim in reverse order? You are assuming that there exists a convex function $k(x)$ first?

Comment: No, it is not. We are given a function $h(x)$ satisfying some property, and we must show how to find a convex function $k(x)$ that we can write $h$ in terms of. In the claim, we do not assume existence of $k(x)$ - but rather, give a formula in terms of $h(x)$ and show that it is convex. Does it make sense? I edited my question to spell it out in more detail.

Comment: Thank you for that. Can you further explain how you were able to change $\alpha I_{i,j}$ to $\frac{\alpha}{2} ||x||^2$ in the equation?

Comment: I just took the second derivative of $\tfrac{\alpha}{2}\|x\|^2$. If it is confusing to you, you can work out the $n=2$ case explicitly. The idea is that $\|x\|^2$ is a sum of $x_1^2+\cdots + x_n^2$. Taking the first partial derivative with respect to $x_i$ leaves only the $x_i^2$ term, whose derivative is $2x_i$. The rest vanish. Then taking the $x_j$ partial of $2x_i$, it is zero unless $i=j$, in which case it is $2$. Now multiply through by $\tfrac{\alpha}{2}$...

Comment: I actually realized right after I made the comment, but thank you for your explanation! One thing also - how did you conclude that the eigenvalues of the Hessian of $h(x) - \frac{a}{2} ||x||^2$ were non-negative?

Comment: Since the eigenvalues of the Hessian of $h(x)$ were all at least $\alpha$, when we subtract $\alpha$ from all the eigenvalues the result has non-negative eigenvalues. The subtraction by $\alpha$ of the eigenvalues is precisely what the subtraction of $\alpha I$ does.